# Can you config a widget after it has been created dynamically?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have been looking for the answer to this but can't find any examples.

I want to know if you can create several buttons or labels or whatever widget in tkinter with all the same variable name and then be able to target that widget directly after its created.

Here is an example of some code that will create 5 buttons with the same variable name and if you press the button it will print the text on said button.

```
import tkinter as tk

btn_names = ["1st Button", "2nd Button", "3rd Button", "4th Button", "5th Button"]

class MyButton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.createButtons()

    def createButtons(self):

        row_count = 0

        for n in range(5):
            someButton = tk.Button(self.parent, text=btn_names[n], command= lambda t=btn_names[n]: self.getText(t))
            someButton.grid(row = row_count, column = 0)
            row_count += 1

    def getText(self, text):
        print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    myApp = MyButton(root)


    root.mainloop()
```

Now what I can't figure out is if it is possible to also make changes to said button. Like I now want to change the buttons background and foreground colors but I have no way of targeting the button I want to edit.

I can't just do this:

`someButton.config(background = "black", foreground = "white")`

as all the buttons are named `someButton`.

So is it possible to be able to edit a widget created in this manor after it has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but it is possible.

Instead of passing a command to your button when you originally create it, add a  line where you configure the command to your lambda function and pass someButton as an argument. Then in your callback function, ensure you configure the button passed to change its background color.

```
import tkinter as tk

btn_names = ["1st Button", "2nd Button", "3rd Button", "4th Button", "5th 
Button"]

class MyButton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.createButtons()

    def createButtons(self):

        row_count = 0

        for n in range(5):
            someButton = tk.Button(self.parent, text=btn_names[n])
            someButton.configure(command=lambda t=btn_names[n], btn = someButton: self.getText(t, btn))
            someButton.grid(row = row_count, column = 0)
            row_count += 1

    def getText(self, text, btn):
        print(text)
        btn.configure(background = 'black')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    myApp = MyButton(root)


    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh that is very useful. I did not know you could add more variables to the lambda like that. Thank you for your answer I believe this will work for my needs.